# How to have two items in the same row

Tags: java, android, android-listview

With android studio I'm trying to create a custom `ListView` where I have two items in the same row. I take an item from a java class and the second item from another java class but It doesn't work. This is what I have:

```
ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RSSItem>(this,
        R.layout.list_item,myRssFeed.getList());
setListAdapter(adapter);

ArrayAdapter<RSSItem2> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RSSItem2>(this,
        R.layout.list_item2,myRssFeed.getSubList());
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call `setListAdapter()` you are completely replacing the ListView's adapter (and thus contents) with the new adapter.

To create a custom ListView that displays content in a more complex fashion (e.g. more than just text or using a more complex data model), you need to create your own implementation of [`BaseAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html).

In addition to the `BaseAdapter`, you will need a single layout file that contains the appropriate Views for displaying the information for both items.

A `BaseAdapter` implementation for this scenario might look something like this:

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private String[] mFirstItems;
    private String[] mSecondItems;
    Context mContext;

    public MyCustomAdapter(String[] firstItems, String[] secondItems, Context context) {
        mFirstItems = firstItems;
        mSecondItems = secondItems;
        mContext = context;
    }

    // Other required overridden methods

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.id.my_row_layout, parent, false);

        // TODO set layout content

        return layout;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but in RSSItem and RSSItem2 I get the title and the description of the feeds. How can I get them if I remove the ArrayAdapters from the MainActivity? If it helps I edit the answer adding more info

Comment: Instead of using String arrays in your custom adapter, you would use RSSItem and RSSItem2 arrays. Pass them in through the constructor. Presumably your row layout would have 4 TextViews (2 titles and 2 descriptions per row) which you would set in `getView()`.

Answer (score 0):

Each list can only have 1 adapter, so when you call `setListAdapter` the second time, the first one is overriden. You should use a single adapter, and a single row layout, which maps the two items into different fields in that layout.